# Equivalent command for software-properties-gtk Additional Drivers switch

Tags: command-line, graphics, additional-drivers

In the Software & Updates window (`software-properties-gtk`) and Additional Drivers tab, I can choose between versions of the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and the "X.Org X server" Nouveau driver. If I didn't have graphical/GUI access, how could I run the equivalent command of switching between preferred drivers from the command line interface?